# HyperSQL database in Tomcat is deleted after Linux restart

Tags: java, tomcat, centos7, hypersql

I am using HyperSQL as database for my Tomcat app. The database server is running from my application and the location of files is in webapps/myapp-folder.

Problem is, that after Linux (Centos 7) restart, the database collide somehow and the database is recreated (all data are deleted). If I restart only the Tomcat, everything is working fine.

My tomcat.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 8.5 servlet container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
Restart=on-failure
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The database folder has full Create and delete rights and group and owner is tomcat user.

The HSQL server is started, when my app starts and for working with database I am using Hibernate:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    properties.setProperty(Environment.URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/my_repository"); 
    properties.setProperty(Environment.USER, xxx);
    properties.setProperty(Environment.PASS, yyy);
    properties.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    properties.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
```

What could be wrong? Why the data are always deleted after PC restart?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the property "HBM2DDL_AUTO" to validate, or even remove it.
This property is responsible for "Automatic schema generation".
You can find the other values or information [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl)

Comment: It is not the problem,  it only happens some times. The problem will be with some bad ending connection of HSQL DB when linux is restarting. H2 embedded works better. :(